# C++: same code and compiler, but different output after each build

Tags: c++, c++14

Greetings to StackOverflow's community! I seriously need someone's help. 
Here is my code that is supposed to print two integers, which are the first and the last indexes of the shortest sentence's symbols in the string given (str).
As you can see, the shortest sentence in this string is "Hey!!!"; character 'H' has index 16 and the last exclamation mark has index 21, so correct output should be: 16 21. 
I've compiled my code using CppShell (cpp.sh) and here's the deal: same code compiled with the same compiler gives different result at each new attempt to build it: 
Attempt #1: 16 21 
Attempt #2: 145921712 4196790 
Attempt #3: 16 21 
Attempt #4: 16 21 
Attempt #5: 1453219648 4196790 
etc.
Could someone please explain me this strange situation? I'm novice at C++, therefore I may not see some obvious mistakes in my code.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <clocale>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus");

    char str[] = "     What's up? Hey!!!    It's a practice... How are you??    ";
    char* ptr = str;
    char* p = ptr;

    int startsym, endsym;
    int startsymMin = 0, endsymMin = 2000; 

    while(*ptr)
    {
        if (*ptr > 64 && *ptr < 91) // capitalized letters 'A'-'Z'
        {
            startsym = strchr(ptr, *ptr)-p;

            while(*ptr)
            {
                if ((*ptr == '!' && *(ptr+1) != '!' && *(ptr+1) != '?')
                    || (*ptr == '?' && *(ptr+1) != '!' && *(ptr+1) != '?')
                    || (*ptr == '.' && *(ptr+1) != '.'))
                {
                    endsym = strchr(ptr, *ptr)-p;
                    break;
                }
                ptr++;
            }
        }

        if (endsym - startsym < endsymMin - startsymMin) {
            startsymMin = startsym;
            endsymMin = endsym;
        }

        ptr++;
    }

    cout << startsymMin << " " << endsymMin << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A lot of your code is going to give you undefined behavior. For instance `ptr++` will add the address inside of the pointer, not the actual value that it is pointing to. In C++, I recommend using std::string instead of an array of chars.

Comment: @mikebayko that it pretty common, and well defined (maybe it isn't very c++ish, but a common idiom in C)

Comment: Look at the first iteration of your loop. The first `if` is false, then at the second `if`, you use variables (`startsym`, `endsym`) which are not initialized.

Comment: I also see a code path that walks `ptr` right past the end of the string. The inner `while` can reach the NUL terminator then the last line of the outer `while ` does `ptr++` and loops back around.

Comment: Something no one ever seems to point novices at is the debugger. The debugger is a fantastic tool that allow you to control the execution of the program allowing you to stop and start, set locations (breakpoints) at which you want the program to stop, and step line by line through the code. Sometimes even instruction by instruction and *backwards*. It also lets you see the state of the program by showing you the contents of variables. You can see what the program is really doing, rather than what you think it is doing. It's kind of soul-crushing in a way, but the time it saves you is amazing.

Comment: If your development environment doesn't have a debugger, I strongly recommend getting one that does. Just about every environment has one, so you shouldn't have to look hard. If you are restricted to using online tools, I've found this one to be useful: https://www.onlinegdb.com/

Comment: @user4581301: the problem is, that this kind of errors may not happen while running under a debugger. But good advice, anyway.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious - that is one of the most inappropriate, yet accurate comments I've read here ever.  Still laughing.  :)

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Yeah I know my code is complete cancer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the first iteration of your loop. The first `if` is false, then at the second `if`, you use variables (`startsym`, `endsym`) which are not initialized.

Initialize these variables as well, and you program will work OK. For this sample string, at least (I think you need to solve other edge cases to make this program work OK for every strings).

Tips:

- use a debugger to find out why your program misbehaves (but,
  unfortunately, in this particular case, debugger may not tell you
  what's the problem).
- if you use MSVC, you can turn on run-time checks for uninitialized variables (/RTCu)
- if you use linux, you can use valgrind to catch this error (and a lot of other kind of errors)

Comment: This has helped! Thanks a lot!